# How to meta-analysis when results are both in hours and days

Tags: meta-analysis

I'm doing a meta-analysis studing lenght of stay after a particular protocol.
However, some studies report their results (meand and SD) in hours and others in days.
How can i change results in days to hours?

Answer (score 1):

The overarching question is: is the length of stay approximately normally distributed? If so:

1. Select a metric, such as hours, to measure the data.
2. Convert all values in days to hours by multiplying both the mean and standard deviation by 24.
3. Determine the standard error (SE) by dividing the standard deviation (SD) by the square root of the sample size (n).
4. Use inverse variance methods to meta-analyze the means and SEs.

If you select days as a metric, you have to divide means (SDs) in hours by 24.